# Using awk to delete multiple numeric lines

Tags: unix, awk, sed, ksh

I need to remove some lines from a log file. The file contains some lines containing 9 digit numbers, sometimes several in a row. I need to find consecutive lines with numbers, and delete every line except the last in each such group.

```
408732560
Error descrNo payment information available
408976296
Error descrNo payment information available
413128144
416192730
375139814
Error descrNo payment information available
```

After processing, I need it too look like this:

```
408732560
Error descrNo payment information available
408976296
Error descrNo payment information available
375139814
Error descrNo payment information available
```

If possible, I would also like to join each number with the following text line as shown below:

```
408732560 Error descrNo payment information available
408976296 Error descrNo payment information available
375139814 Error descrNo payment information available
```

Comment: Does the solution require the use of awk, or could (common) command line utility be used?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty simple way of doing it:

```bash
$ cat f
408732560
Error descrNo payment information available
408976296
Error descrNo payment information available
413128144
416192730
375139814
Error descrNo payment information available
$ cat f | awk '/^[0-9]{9}$/ { v=$0 } !/^[0-9]{9}$/ { print v " "$0; v="" } END { if (v) print v }'
408732560 Error descrNo payment information available
408976296 Error descrNo payment information available
375139814 Error descrNo payment information available
```

Essentially, if we encounter a line consisting of 9 digits, we store that line in a buffer. When we encounter a non-9 digit line, we print whatever was in the buffer, and then empty it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=="Error"{print e,$0;next}{e=$1}' file
408732560 Error descrNo payment information available
408976296 Error descrNo payment information available
375139814 Error descrNo payment information available
```

If the lines starts with `Error` then print it along with the last error number stored, if it doesn't store the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'h
$  {x
:cycle
   s/\(\n[0-9]* \)[^[:cntrl:]]*\1/\1/g
   t cycle
   s/.//p
   }' YourFile
```

Load the whole file in buffer, remove any line that start with the same number as the next one. Cycle this action until there are no more occurence, print the result (just remove the first \n added at the first action)